# Getting Error : moment.duration is not a function

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to **convert seconds in HH:MM:SS** format. I am getting an error moment.duration is not a function.

var moment = require("moment-duration-format");

moment.duration(123, "seconds").format("hh:mm:ss");

Answer (score 16):

The `moment-duration-format` plugin [depends on](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format#module) `moment`, so you should import/require it first:

```
var moment = require("moment")
require("moment-duration-format");

moment.duration(123, "seconds").format("hh:mm:ss");
```

Comment: That i did. npm install moment as well as npm install moment-duration-format

Comment: Yeah, `npm install` just downloads the package into `node_modules` directory. You need to import it in your script to use it. Glad it worked. :)

Answer (score 8):

I tried both

`import 'moment-duration-format';`

and

`require("moment-duration-format");`

but it did not solve my problem and I was still getting `TypeError: moment.duration(...).format is not a function` so I took a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-duration-format to find how to correctly set it up and I found out that I have to call it and pass moment in order to make it work correctly.

```js
import momentDurationFormatSetup from 'moment-duration-format';
momentDurationFormatSetup(moment);
```